# Oauth2 Client Application authorization, using Symfony

Tags: php, rest, symfony, oauth-2.0

I would like to protect some end-point of the API only to be accessed by "Client Application" (instead of for a user with a role). The system is using Oauth2, and I have access and can modify the Authorization Server and the Client Application.

I am using Symfony2 and there is an example [How to Authenticate Users with API Keys](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html) , but the example is only for the user's token (Using ApiKeyUserProvider) this made me think that maybe Is not the right approach.

Do you know any example for this problem, should I try other approach?

Comment: take a look at this bundle  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle

Comment: The user's token is what is used by the Symfony security system to grant authorization.  So one way or another your client needs to end up with a token.  Doesn't have to be a user token.  You can make a client token if you like.

Comment: Thank you. So Is the right approach. The problem that I see is when I use ApiKeyAuthenticator that implements  this interface   \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\SimpleAuthenticatorInterface::authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)  This UserProvider is clear only for users, because I can not loadUserByUsername if it is a client.